# How do I program Exponential Backoff into a Google Sheets Script?

Tags: google-sheets, scripting, exponential-backoff

How would one program Exponential Backoff into this script so that when I run into an error it will attempt to run again?

**Errors being encountered:**

- There are too many scripts running simultaneously for this Google user account.
- Too many simultaneous invocations: Spreadsheets
- Exceeded maximum execution time
- Exception: Too many simultaneous invocations: Spreadsheets at onEdit(Code:3:9)
- Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id __________.

**Script:**

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "FORD" ) {
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 3) {
     
      var nextCell = r.offset(0,19);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' )
        nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
    }
    
    if( r.getColumn() == 7) {
      var nextCell = r.offset(0,16);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' )
        nextCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
    }
  }
}
```

Any other advice to improve my script is always appreciated!  =)

Answer (score 0):

For the errors you are mentioning, exponential backoff would not be useful since they are quota errors:

Check out [quota limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations)

[image: limitations]

Comment: Has this answer helped you on your issue? Have you checked if the issue is indeed a quota issue?